# HTML5 Video on IE11 z-index issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html5-video

I'm working on displaying divs over the html5 video player using the z-index.
For Chrome and FF no issues but for IE yes.

On fullscreen, IE use z-index 2147483647 (max one) and my divs are not displayed in this case.
I tried to change the z-index value of the IE html5 player but without success.

Is there a way to display a div over in this case for IE?

Thanks

Comment: This should work - I have achieved what you described in IE. Can we have a look at your code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Florestan06 Sure, take a look here: http://pastebin.com/8Gei8qHh

Comment: I tried your code but I am having trouble to reproduce your issue - even to make it works cross browser. Can you tear it down to the core component in a working JSfiddle? Sorry I cannot help you much as of now.